# How to perform model action the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where to put a method such as this? I'm using [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). I see there's a rails version but the project I'm using uses money gem and I wish not to add another gem if I could get away with something simple.

I have a model and a column called "cost" which is an integer. Value is saved as cents:

```rb
# maybe I could use before_save to change the value.
# but this is done in controller:
record.cost.to_d * 100
```

I use money to display the value

```rb
Money.new(record.cost, "GBP").format #=> £49.99
```

On an edit page, the input field is shown as `4999`. I need to format that value to show `49.99`. How to format? I thought of using the Record model for that:

```rb
# Record.rb
after_find :convert_to_amount, on: :edit

def convert_to_amount
    self.cost = (self.cost.to_d / 100).to_s
end
```

Gives an error:

> Unknown key: :on. Valid keys are: :if, :unless, :prepend

I only need to perform this conversion when editing. How to use [after_find](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) when editing? Should this be in the controller? How to do something like this the rails way?

Comment: I think you can do that however you're presenting that data, it can be with a helper method or a decorator if using a Rails view, or in a serializer if you're returning just a JSON. Or do you need to persist that custom format in the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "virtual attribute" to handle this conversion between form inputs and model fields. For example:

1. Add two methods `cost_gbp_input=` and `cost_gbp_input` in the `Record` model as below.

app/model/record.rb

```
class Record
  # ...

  validate :check_cost_gbp_input # do some validations if needed

  def cost_gbp_input=(given_value)
    self.cost = (BigDecimal(given_value) * 100).to_i
  rescue ArgumentError
    # keep cost not changed when given value is invalid
  ensure
    @cost_gbp_input = given_value
  end

  def cost_gbp_input
    return nil if cost.blank?

    (cost.to_d / 100).to_s
  end

  private

  def check_cost_gbp_input
    return if @cost_gbp_input.blank?

    BigDecimal(@cost_gbp_input)
  rescue ArgumentError
    @errors.add(:cost_gbp_input, :invalid)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Then you can use `cost_gbp_input` in forms and controllers, just like other real attributes.

2. Use `cost_gbp_input` instead of `cost` in new/edit form.

app/views/records/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @record do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :cost_gbp_input %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

3. Add `cost_gbp_input` to the strong parameter in `RecordsController`

app/controllers/records_controller.rb

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)
    if @record.save
      redirect_to record_path(@record)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @record.update(record_params)
      redirect_to record_path(@record)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:cost_gbp_input)
  end

  # ...
end
```